# Why not showing the return value of the function?

Tags: reactjs, function, return, render

function
in console.log I can see the correct results

```
     const getName = (id) => {

        var name = "";
        axios.get( `http://localhost:3001/students/names/${id}`).then((response) => {

          name = response.data[0].Fname + " " + response.data[0].Lname;
          console.log(name);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

        return name;
        
      };
```

render method

```
 {results.map((value,key)=>(

                                      <tr key={key}>

                                          <td className='columnData'>
                                              { (getName(value.Student_ID))  }
                                          </td>
```

Why not showing the return value of the function ?

Comment: In addition to the above linked duplicate... *In React* what you're missing here is the concept of *state*.  Your asynchronous operation shouldn't *return* the value, it should *update state* with the value.  Then the render method just displays whatever the current state is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a async function so if you want to get the name just make a state.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const getName = (id) => {
        axios.get( `http://localhost:3001/students/names/${id}`).then((response) => {

          setName(response.data[0].Fname + " " + response.data[0].Lname);
          console.log(name);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

        return name;
        
      };
```

then you can use the name where ever you want

Comment: Thanks it working. but changing the  results continuesly

Answer (score 1):

You have to await the Axios get method:

```
const getName = async (id) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/students/names/${id}`);
    const name = response.data[0].Fname + " " + response.data[0].Lname;
    return name;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return "";
  }
};
```

Comment: How will `getName` be awaited in this case?  React render methods can't be `async`.